# What is the rigorous definition of a cycle in non-Euclidean geometries?

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry, cayley-klein

The cycles of Euclidean geometry are: Points, lines, circles.

The cycles of hyperbolic geometry are: Points, lines, circles, hypercycles, horocycles.

There is a commonality between these: These are all orbits of some point under a connected Lie subgroup of the congruence group. In Euclidean geometry, the congruence group is $E(2)$, and in hyperbolic geometry it's $PGL(2,\mathbb R)$.

The problem is that there is some ambiguity in what a hyperbolic hypercycle is: Under one definition, it has two connected components instead of one. But then it's not the orbit of a point under a connected Lie subgroup. If this definition of a hyperbolic hypercycle gets adopted, then what then does the word "cycle" mean in general?

#### Further thoughts

What happens if you use a Cayley-Klein model? In a CK geometry (which both Euclidean and hyperbolic geometries are), a cycle could perhaps be defined as a quadric closed under a connected Lie subgroup of the congruence group. Then a hyperbolic hypercycle has two connected components instead of one, as desired.

Comment: @Blue Thank you.

Comment: There is no canonical definition: pick one which you find most useful.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "point cycle." From the perspective of Klein geometry the "geometric figures" in a geometry with automorphism group $G$ are given, in full generality, by the elements of every quotient $G/H$ (and if $G$ is a Lie group we should ask for $H$ to be a closed subgroup, I guess). The relationships between figures (intersections and so forth) are given by orbits in products $G/H \times G/K$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, sorry. In Isaak Yaglom's "Complex Numbers In Geometry", Yaglom lists out the point cycles and line cycles of each Cayley-Klein geometry. He doesn't define rigorously what he means by either kind of cycle. In the Euclidean case, the line cycles are: Points (considered as the set of all lines going through them), cycles (considered as the set of all their tangent lines), a line on its own (understood as a singleton set), and the set of all lines parallel to a given line.

Comment: Isaak Yaglom was a popular mathematics writer in the USSR.

Comment: So... what is a "point cycle"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well, that's kind of what I'm asking. I think a point cycle is a quadric closed under a connected Lie subgroup. A line cycle by contrast is... the same thing, but the projective dual, I guess?

Comment: Maybe I should just say "cycle" instead of "point cycle". I guess this is confusing enough

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I got rid of the confusion. There are now only *cycles*, not "point cycles".

Comment: So what is a "cycle"? You refer to a concept which has been left undefined by one specific author; why would anyone know what this author means except them?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The term gets used in hyperbolic geometry. It also gets used in Laguerre geometries. It appears to have a general definition, but I don't know what it is. And that's why I'm asking.

Comment: **Correction**: Where in a comment above I said "cycles (considered as the set of all their tangent lines)", that should say "**circles** (considered as the set of all their tangent lines)". A circle, considered as the set of its tangent lines, is one example of a line cycle.

Comment: I doubt that this question has a answer any better than to quote from Yaglom's book as you have done in one of your own comments. For example, I've never seen this terminology (in my 4+ decades of studying hyperbolic geometry).